# Is drawing God allowed in Islam?

Tags: allah, drawing

Recently, Charlie Hebdo published an edition that had God carrying a kalashnikov on the cover, and a news organisation reportedly decided not to show the cover because it had an image of God (apparently having an image of God was enough, as opposed to him carrying a gun or having blood splattered on him). From [After finding out that Charlie Hebdo cover satirizes God, MSNBC censors it](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/erik-wemple/wp/2016/01/07/after-finding-out-that-charlie-hebdo-cover-satirizes-god-msnbc-censors-it/) (the link has no pictures of the prophet, just an image of God)

> In a reply that merits no further commentary from this blog, the MSNBC
>   rep says that the network showed the current Charlie Hebdo cover up
>   until it confirmed that the image was of God. “Once we found that out,
>   we stopped showing it,” notes the rep.

Is drawing the God of Islam, Christianity and Judaism allowed in Islam?

I tried googling about the topic, but mainly got hits about the drawing of the prophet Mohammed in Islam.

The following are related, but don't seem to answer this question: [Are depictions of the prophet PBUH forbidden Islamically?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24174/are-depictions-of-the-prophet-pbuh-forbidden-islamically) (about the Prophet), and [Is it permissible to make and watch TV programs with living creatures in them?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/is-it-permissible-to-make-and-watch-tv-programs-with-living-creatures-in-them) (about living creatures).

Comment: How would one draw God?

Comment: Is there any God at all ??!!

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, the concept of God is that he is **the Creator** of all creations and nothing came before him. He is not human, man, creature or any other creation and so there is no physical image to draw him into.

> "...There is nothing that resembles him, 
>       and He is the Hearing, the Seeing..." (Ash-Shuraa 42:11)

So as Muslims we draw it in Arabic text or calligraphy which is not the same as drawing a portrait of a person:

**Allah**:

[image: Name of God in Arabic " Allah "]

Same for **Muhammad ﷺ** :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a child, I saw a movie about the story of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH). But his face was never shown. Most scenes were how he sees. When I asked why he is not shown, this is what I got as an answer.
"There are people who worship images and sculptures and if someone sees his face, people will say that this is the real Prophet and start worshiping him."
This is actually a fact that our history teaches us. So if some guy says, I saw God in my dream and this is how He looks like, people will blindly worship that picture. So I guess it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i've been searching for it as well to find its image, to see anyone able to create something which is not a creation.

If you based it in human logic, its freaking impossible to create an outer being without using the concept of human as a referal. Try and look at movies as well, they create an alien robot still based on human module. Our brain cant surpase that level of logic because no one have seen god.

But if you start drawing god, u would definetly would use human being/animals/moon and etc. as referal for drawing, which is the creation of the creator. Haha..thats what get things mess up. Mixing the resources of the creation and coming up with the image of GOD.

Its insane to draw someting you never seen. If you look up the list of gods, there are thousands of other god image from various religion, White Jesus, Korean Jesus, Black Jesus and Etc , Zeus, Buddha, Shiva, Ganesan and etc.

All of this is have an image of the creation itself, human being, human beings+animal, animal, and etc.

Its impossible to create an image of the Creator without using the creation as a reference.

And that left with only one god left without image out of all these thousands of gods with image,

ALLAH,  The one an only god that nobody able to create the image as its impossible. Trust me, its impossible.

Read the Qur'an and listen to what Allah has to say. It make perfect sense.

In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful. [All] praise is [due] to Allah, Lord of the worlds-The Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful, Sovereign of the Day of Recompense. It is You we worship and You we ask for help. Guide us to the straight path -The path of those upon whom You have bestowed favor, not of those who have evoked [Your] anger or of those who are astray.

Al-Fatihah 1-7
Qur'an

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on answering the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).